# Prevent Task from starting

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

Class `TaskHolder` has a property of type `Task`. I pass `Task` as a parameter into constructor and it starts immediately. Is there a way to prevent it from start?

```
public class Worker
{
    public class TaskHolder
    {
        public TaskHolder(Task objective)
        {
            Objective = objective;
        }

        public Task Objective { get; set; }
    }

    public async Task DoSomething()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        Debugger.Break(); // Task starts, so debugger stops here!
        // Is there a way to prevent it from start?
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task TempTest()
    {
        // programm starts here:
        var t1 = new TaskHolder(DoSomething());
        await Task.Delay(10000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want it to start? Is this for debugging?

Comment: `TaskHolder` in real code has `List<Task> Steps {get; set;}` that holds multiple steps to perform one by one, not simultaneously. I want to perform this steps one by one periodically. Now I see my implementation is wrong. B.t.w. steps became 'RanToCompletion' state after first run, so the only way to start them again is to recreate them.

Comment: "`List<Task> Steps {get; set;}` that holds multiple steps to perform one by one, not simultaneously" - that simply isn't  what `Task` represents. It really sounds like that should be `List<Action>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Task` represents the now-or-future result  of an awaitable operation. If that task has already started, that's interesting - but it has nothing to do with the code that is **receiving** the task.

If you don't want to start something yet, you should probably be passing an `Action`. You can create a `Task` from an `Action` via `Task.Run`. Or you can simply invoke the action via `action()` or action.Invoke()`.

If what you want  to run is explicitly asynchronous: you can pass `Func<Task>`. Again, you can start  such a delegate with `Task.Run` if you want  a `Task` that represents the final state. Or you can just  invoke it.

(whether to `Invoke()` it  or pass it to `Task.Run()` depends on whether you want it to use your thread for any of it)

Ultimately, when you called `DoSomething()`, **you** started the code running. A timer was scheduled by the `Task.Delay`, and then the code continued into `TaskHolder`.

Comment: So in simple words. If I create a Task instance it can starts immediately, I can't control it. And why `new Task()` is an exception from this rule then?

Comment: @AsValeO no, that isn't what it means; it is more nuanced than that. In this case, the `Task` you got was the result of an `async` method that **you started**. There are other types of `Task`. For example, if you use a `TaskCompletionSource<T>`, the `.Task` from that  can be handed to people and will not do anything at all. But it also doesn't represent a future runnable operation! You need separate code (perhaps an IO callback) to trigger the completion state (`TrySetResult`, etc). So again: the right thing to use depends on what you want to do - something that isn't clear in your example.

Comment: You've helped me so much!

Comment: I would suggest `Func<Task>` rather than `Action`, but the core idea of using a delegate instead of `Task` is correct.